# Análisis de un problema con el tiempo de ejecución de un código en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Nota: Esta pregunta no tiene una respuesta cerrada puesto que lo que
>   busca es encontrar defectos y bajar el tiempo de computación del
>   código. Si se encuentra algún defecto obvio, puedo proceder entonces a editar el título de la pregunta para que la respuesta atienda a un objetivo más concreto y que sea más útil así para la comunidad.

He estado mejorando y actualizando recientemente con ayuda de la comunidad un código con el que hago una serie de simulaciones. Copio una versión del mismo a modo de ejemplo mínimo abajo.

El número de simulaciones puede fijarse al declarar la variable `simulaciones` en `main()`. En el ejemplo 100.

En el ejemplo corremos las simulaciones con 4 jugadores, 4 señales y 4 "s" o "sigmas". Es decir:

```
jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}
```

He analizado el tiempo de simulación utilizando `cProfile.run()` y he comprobado que el tiempo de 100 simulaciones para estas cuatro variables es 1.165 segundos.

El problema que tengo es que el tiempo de la simulación cuando aumento el número de elementos en dichas variables crece enormemente. Por ejemplo, si duplico el número de elementos en estas variables:

```
jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8"]
s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
s2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2, 5: s1, 6: s1, 7: s2, 8: s2}
```

En este caso el tiempo de simulación es 123.126 segundos. Por lo tanto, con esa progresión, pensar en por ejemplo 1000 simulaciones para 100 jugadores llevaría muchísimo tiempo.

Por lo tanto, el objetivo es bajar el tiempo de simulación de este código lo máximo posible, manteniendo eso sí, el mismo resultado en el archivo csv obtenido.

Si hay algún defecto muy obvio que yo no vea, o cualquier sugerencia, estaría muy agradecido.

```
from __future__ import division
from random import random, seed
import random as rand
from bisect import bisect
import csv
from itertools import permutations
from skbio.diversity.alpha import shannon

def choice(opciones, probs):
    probAcumuladas = list()
    aux = 0
    for p in probs:
        aux += p
        probAcumuladas.append(aux)
    r = random() * probAcumuladas[-1]
    op = bisect(probAcumuladas, r)
    return opciones[op]


class Jugador:
    def __init__(self, nombre, senales, sigma, b, x, m):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.senales = senales
        self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
        self.sigma = sigma[:]  
        self.b = b
        self.x = x
        self.m = m

    def __str__(self):
        return "Jugador_{}".format(self.nombre)

    def with_b(self, muestra, observa, r, idx):
        if not (muestra == observa == 0):
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - self.b) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * self.b * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        else:
            result = (
                ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (1.0 - self.x) * muestra / r)
                + ((0.98) * (1.0 - 0) * (self.x) * observa / r)
                + ((0.98) * 0 * self.sigma[idx])
                + ((self.m / 8))
            )
        return result

    def choose(self, r):
        probs = [
            self.with_b(
                self.mem_mostradas[op], self.men_observadas[op], r, indx
            )
            for indx, op in enumerate(self.senales)
        ]
        elecc = choice(self.senales, probs)
        return elecc

class Partida:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, emparejamientos, senales, sigmas, b, x, m):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        self.senales = senales
        self.jugadores = {
            nombre: Jugador(nombre, senales, sigmas[nombre], b, x, m)
            for nombre in jugadores
        }
        self.memoria = list()
        self.entropy = float()

    def generar_senales(self):
        yield dict(zip(self.jugadores, self.senales))
        r = 1
        while True:
            eleccs = {}
            for jugador in self.jugadores.values():
                eleccs[jugador.nombre] = jugador.choose(r)
            r += 1
            yield eleccs

    def jugar(self):
        gen_sens = self.generar_senales()
        for ronda in self.emparejamientos:
            senales = next(gen_sens)
            self.memoria.append(senales)
            for jugador1, jugador2 in ronda:
                self.jugadores[jugador1].men_observadas[senales[jugador2]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].men_observadas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador1].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador1]] += 1
                self.jugadores[jugador2].mem_mostradas[senales[jugador2]] += 1

def grupo(jugadores, n=100):
    todos = set()
    for caso in permutations(jugadores):
        gen = list(zip(*[iter(caso)] * 2))
        gen = tuple(sorted(tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in gen))
        todos.add(gen)
    todos = list(todos)
    rand.shuffle(todos)
    return todos[:n]

def main():
    jugadores = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    senales = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"]
    network = grupo(jugadores)
    emparejamientos = [list(elem) for elem in network]

    patron = 1

    s1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]
    s2 = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    sigmas = {1: s1, 2: s1, 3: s2, 4: s2}

    muestras = [{'b': 0.0, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.1, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.2, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.3, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.4, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.5, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.6, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.7, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.8, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 0.9, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02},
        {'b': 1.0, 'x': 0.5, 'm': 0.02}]

    muestras = [d for d in muestras for _ in range(1)]

    simulaciones = 100

    estadisticas = {
        sim: {
            jugador: {
                muestra: {
                    senal: [0 for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1)]
                    for senal in senales
                }
                for muestra in range(len(muestras))
            }
            for jugador in jugadores
        }
        for sim in range(simulaciones)
    }

    for sim in range(simulaciones):
        network = grupo(jugadores)
        emparejamientos = [list(elem) for elem in network]
        for mu in range(len(muestras)):
            juego = Partida(
                jugadores,
                emparejamientos,
                senales,
                sigmas,
                muestras[mu]["b"],
                muestras[mu]["x"],
                muestras[mu]["m"],
            )
            juego.jugar()
            for n, ronda in enumerate(juego.memoria):
                for jugador, senal in ronda.items():
                    estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][n] += 1

    with open("datos.csv", "w", newline="") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(
            csvfile, delimiter=";", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
        )
        writer.writerow(
            ["Sim", "Muestra", "Jugador", "Ronda", "Patron", "b", "x", "m"]
            + senales
            + ["sumpop"]
            + ["shannon"]
        )

        for jugador in jugadores:
            for sim in range(simulaciones):
                for mu in range(len(muestras)):
                    for ronda in range(1, len(emparejamientos) + 1):
                        aux = [
                            estadisticas[sim][jugador][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux1 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][1][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux2 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][2][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux3 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][3][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]
                        aux4 = [
                            estadisticas[sim][4][mu][senal][ronda - 1]
                            for senal in senales
                        ]

                        summation_pop = []
                        for i in range(len(aux1)):
                            summation_pop.append(aux1[i] + aux2[i] + aux3[i] + aux4[i])
                        writer.writerow(
                            [
                                sim + 1,
                                mu + 1,
                                jugador,
                                ronda,
                                patron,
                                muestras[mu]["b"],
                                muestras[mu]["x"],
                                muestras[mu]["m"],
                            ]
                            + aux
                            + [summation_pop]
                            + [shannon(summation_pop)]
                        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yo intentaría usar `cProfile` para obtener información más detallada (que este módulo te puede proporcionar) de qué función es la que se está llevando más peso en el total del tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: De todas formas da la impresión de que la simulación que pretendes tenga una complejidad exponencial, con lo que es de esperar que, por mucho que optimices, aumentar el tiempo de ejecucíón crezca exponencialmente con el tamaño (numero de jugadores). Es decir, que aumentar el número de jugadores a 4 más, puede causar un incremento del cómputo en un factor por ejemplo 10**4. Voy a echar un vistazo al código a ver si se confirma mi sospecha en cuanto a su complejidad.

Comment: @abufalia gracias. En efecto, también yo sospecho algo así. El código está bastante trabajado y creo que quizá hay funciones que se puedan optimizar ligeramente, pero no mucho más. He analizado el `código` con cProfile y la función que consume casi todo el tiempo es `main()`. Los demás procesos no consumen nada significativo. Me he animado a subir el código con este propósito en caso que alguien vea cosas obvias que yo no soy capaz de ver o por si existe alguna herramienta para que pueda ayudar a bajar sustancialemnte el tiempo de estas simulaciones. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hombre, normal que `main()` sea la que más tarda si mides el tiempo "entre inicio y fin" pues de ese modo el tiempo atribuido a `main()` incluye también el de todas las funciones a las que ésta llama, ¡que son todas! Tendrías que mirar el tiempo que gasta cada función "en sí misma", descontando el gastado en llamar a otras (sería la columna `tottime` en vez de `cumtime`). Aunque es verdad que en tu caso `main()` es bien larga, así que quizás su `tottime` sea también el mayor

Comment: Habría que buscar bucles dentro de bucles, que son quienes aumentan la complejidad. Y ver si se pueden evitar. Por ejemplo (no digo que sea el caso, no lo he estudiado en detalle), recorrer una lista para buscar en ella un elemento es una operación más costosa que buscar una clave en un diccionario.

Comment: @abufalia gracias por los comentarios, muy útiles. Sí, en efecto, es normal que `main()` sea la función que más tiempo consume. He estado analizando el problema un poco más y he comprobado que el método `sorted` dentro de la función `grupo` es lo que más `tottime` gasta. Esta función la diseñé con la idea de randomizar la estructura de emparejamientos (lista que contiene tuplas-emparejamientos de listas-rondas) en cada simulación. Quizá ese es uno de los puntos (quizá no el único) donde pueda intentar optimizar el código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tras revisar un poco el código observo el siguiente "nudo gordiano":

```
def grupo(jugadores, n=100):
    todos = set()
    for caso in permutations(jugadores):
        gen = list(zip(*[iter(caso)] * 2))
        gen = tuple(sorted(tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in gen))
        todos.add(gen)
    todos = list(todos)
    rand.shuffle(todos)
    return todos[:n]
```

La función `grupo()` tiene una complejidad altísima, en términos de tiempo de ejecución y de memoria consumida.

- Contiene un bucle que itera por `permutation(jugadores)`. El número de permutaciones de N jugadores es factorial de N (N!), de modo que la complejidad es como mínimo factorial (esto es casi exponencial).
- Además, cada iteración en ese bucle llama a dos sort anidados. El `sort()` más interno no es preocupante, pues las tuplas que ordena tienen tamaño 2. Pero está dentro de otro `sort()` que debe ordenar el resultado de iterar `for pair in gen`, y `gen` tiene longitud N/2. Así que ese bucle se ejecuta N/2 veces y por cada ejecución, se llama a un `sort()` para ordenar una lista de N/2 elementos. Como mínimo esto tiene complejidad N<sup>2</sup> (eso asumiendo que el `sort()` tenga complejidad O(N) que en realidad tiene más). Y lo peor es que esto se llama *para cada permutación* y hay N! permutaciones.
- De modo que `sort()` se está llamando en total `N!*(N/2)*(N/2)`. Un montón de veces. Por eso su total de tiempo acumulado es tan grande.
- Además, cada `gen` que obtienes, la vas metiendo en la lista `todos`, con lo que el tamaño de esa lista también será factorial de N. Teniendo en cuenta lo rápido que crece el factorial, no me extrañaría que la lista en cuestión acabe ocupando toda la RAM del ordenador, y éste tenga que empezar a tirar a hacer *swapping* al disco duro, lo que ralentizaría aún más el programa.

Para que te hagas una idea, con 8 jugadores salen 40320 permutaciones. La lista `todos` tendría en su interior 40320 tuplas, cada una de las cuales tendría 4 elementos (cada uno de los cuales sería otra tupla con dos jugadores). Teniendo en cuenta que cada tupla ocupa 48 bytes, más 8 por cada elemento que contenga, más lo que ocupe el correspondiente elemento, el tamaño mínimo ocupado en memoria por esa lista sería de al menos 38MB. No es tanto, pero crece alarmantemente con el número de jugadores.

Para tan solo 10 jugadores (3628800 permutaciones) la lista ya ocuparía más de 3.5 GB, alarmantemente cerca de los 4GB de RAM que tiene un ordenador modesto (y en esa RAM debe caber también todo el operativo y el resto de aplicaciones que tengas abiertas).

Y para 11 jugadores (39916800 permutaciones) la lista ya se pone en más de 37GB!!! (la "magia" del crecimiento factorial)

Teniendo en cuenta que al final te vas a quedar sólo con 100 elementos de los miles de millones generados, creo que se trata claramente de un enfoque erróneo.

No acabo de entender bien el cometido de esta función, pero si me lo explicas, seguramente habrá una forma más eficiente de generar esos 100 elementos sin tener que generar todas las permutaciones posibles, que es lo que hace explotar tu problema.

## Edición

Tratando de comprender el objetivo de la función `grupo()` me parece ver que se trata de obtener emparejamientos "al azar" de los jugadores. Por ejemplo, si los jugadores son `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` el resultado de ejecutar `grupo()` sería una lista con elementos como:

```
[((1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 5), (4, 6)),
 ((1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4)),
... etc
]
```

Una forma mucho más eficiente de lograr una lista así sería:

1. Barajar al azar la lista de jugadores
2. Retornar la lista barajada, agrupada de 2 en 2
3. Repetir paso 1

   Hasta haber generado tantos elementos como se desee

El inconveniente de mi método es que podría retornar el mismo emparejamiento varias veces, mientras que tu técnica de generarlos a partir de todas las permutaciones posibles nunca repetiría emparejamiento. Es más, tu implementación (al ordenar las tuplas y meterlas en un `set()`) considerará estos dos agrupamientos "el mismo":

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)] y
[(1,2), (6,5), (3,4)]
```

Y en el resultado aparecerá el primero de ellos pero nunca el segundo, pues es una reordenación del primero. No veo claro por qué este énfasis en evitar que se repitan emparejamientos, si el objetivo es generarlos "al azar". En un emparejamiento verdaderamente al azar las repeticiones de emparejamientos aparecerían con cierta frecuencia.

Mi implementación sugerida sería por tanto:

```
def grupo2(jugadores, n=20):
  caso = jugadores[:]
  resultado = []
  for _ in range(n):
    rand.shuffle(caso)
    gen = list(zip(*[iter(caso)] * 2))
    resultado.append(gen)
  return resultado
```

Otra diferencia entre mi implementación y la tuya es que la mía siempre retornará 100 elementos en la lista resultado (o el número `n` que se le pase como parámetro), mientras que en tu implementación el número de elementos retornado depende de cuántos jugadores haya, ya que para 6 jugadores por ejemplo sólo hay 15 emparejamientos posibles, una vez descontados los "repetidos por reordenación").

Mi implementación produciría por ejemplo los siguientes grupos:

```
[[(3, 1), (5, 6), (4, 2)],
 [(6, 1), (3, 5), (2, 4)],
 [(5, 6), (4, 1), (2, 3)],
 [(1, 3), (6, 5), (2, 4)],
 [(2, 1), (6, 5), (4, 3)],
... etc ... hasta 100
]
```

Si mi implementación es válida (es decir, si no te importa que aparezcan emparejamientos repetidos), sería muchísimo más óptima, al depender tanto el tiempo de ejecución como la memoria consumida sólo de cuántos emparejamientos pidas (el parámetro `n=100`) y no de cuántos jugadores haya, y el crecimiento del tiempo de cómputo según aumenta `n` sería prácticamente lineal.

Comment: gracias por esta propuesta. Que no se den emparejamientos repetidos me importaba más con simulaciones con un número pequeño de rondas. Al aumentar el número de rondas a 100, el efecto de la repetición puede que sea despreciable. Así que a lo mejor esta solución tiene sentido para lo que busco. Voy a estudiarlo estos días.

Comment: En realidad, aunque con mi enfoque pueden aparecer grupos repetidos, lo cierto es que la probabilidad de que ello ocurra no es muy alta. Depende del número de jugadores. Para 8 jugadores existen 8!=40320 permutaciones, y vamos a extraer 100 de ellas al azar, con reposición. La probabilidad de que las 100 sean diferentes , si no me he equivocado, es más del 88%, y crece cuantos más jugadores consideres. Para 10 jugadores te saldrán los 100 grupos diferentes con una probabilidad del 99.86%. Y aún si tienes la mala fortuna de que alguno se repita, no creo que sea problema

Comment: Y si realmente no quieres que se repitan, basta que vayas añadiendo cada grupo que construyes a un conjunto, en vez de a una lista, y repetir hasta que el conjunto tenga 100 elementos. Así te garantizas que son todos diferentes y para un número de jugadores mayor de 8 no tadaría mucho, al ser baja la probabilidad de "colisión".